# Как выполнить итерацию словаря по двум и более значениям?

Tags: python

~
могу я использовать такой синтаксис для поиска в словаре по нескольким значениям одновременно?
~

Имеется предположим файл со строками в виде словаря:

```py
{"Number": "120", "Card": "21905678", "Contract": "Yes", "ID": "1"}
{"Number": "111", "Card": "34565699", "Contract": "Yes", "ID": "2"}
{"Number": "123", "Card": "45000012", "Contract": "No", "ID": "3"}
```

я хочу из этого словаря получать данные по нескольким значениям
в условии я ввожу `v == '120'`  и  `v == '1'`, то на выходе я должен получить строку где есть эти значения т.е. вот эту

```
"Number": "120", "Card": "21905678", "Contract": "Yes", "ID": "1"
```

если в условии v =="123" and v =="3" то на выходе должна быть строка :

```
{"Number": "123", "Card": "45000012", "Contract": "No", "ID": "3"}
```

и т.д.

```py
ln = {"Number": "120", "Card": "21905678", "Contract": "Yes", "ID": "2"}

for k, v in ln.items():
    if v == "100" and v == "2":
        print('Number', ln['Number'],end='; ')
        print('ID', ln['ID'])

    elif v == "120" and v == "2":
        print('Number', ln['Number'],end='; ')
        print('ID', ln['ID'])
```

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, но наверное `if v in ["100", "120"]:`

Comment: Нажмите [edit], чтобы дополнить вопрос. Комментарии не для этого.

Comment: возможно я не правильно сформулировал вопрос,  но суть такова ,  как я могу в условии задать несколько значений
if v == '120' and v =='2'   или так это не работает?

Comment: Так я вам это и написал. Используйте `in`

Comment: при использовании  `in`  выводится двойной результат.

Comment: После правки вопроса стало совсем непонятно. Попробуйте описать словами что вы хотите? Вывести значения словаря, если в списке значений есть два значения (100 и 2)?

Comment: То как вы написали в примере - ну не может же `v` **одновременно** быть равно двум разным значениям. Непонятно, что вы имеете в виду. Приведите прямо в виде примеров в вопросе: вот с такими данными должен выйти такой результат, а с вот такими такой.

Comment: А файл вы как читаете? Его же ещё парсить нужно. Если там всё-таки список и через запятую `[{...},{...}], то можно прочитать как `JSON`, но так, как вы написали - это ещё возиться нужно с обработкой файла.

Comment: как раз с файлом проблем нет ,  в нем содержатся строки в виде словаря.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорей всего нет необходимости вообщей по сущностям словаря бегать через `for`. Обратитесь на прямую по ключам и сравните значения

```py
ln = {"Number": "120", "Card": "21905678", "Contract": "Yes", "ID": "2"}

if ln["Number"] == "120" and ln["ID"] == "2":
    print('Number', ln['Number'],end='; ')
    print('ID', ln['ID'])
elif ln["Number"] == "100" and ln["ID"] == "2":
    print('Number', ln['Number'],end='; ')
    print('ID', ln['ID'])
```

Вывод

```
Number 120; ID 2
```

Полный скрипт с чтением данных из файла, выглядит вот так:

```py
with open("test.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        dict_ = json.loads(line)
        if dict_["Number"] == "120" and dict_["ID"] == "2":
            print('Number', dict_['Number'],end='; ')
            print('ID', dict_['ID'])
        elif dict_["Number"] == "100" and dict_["ID"] == "2":
            print('Number', dict_['Number'],end='; ')
            print('ID', dict_['ID'])
```

Comment: Спасибо Dmitry это то что нужно!

Comment: @VasilijsLaskovskis на здоровье, можете оценить ответ и пометить его как принятый. Если возникают вопросы, то можно найти инфу здесь [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)